# Htaccess Regex won't match

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm in desperate need of a quick tip.

Trying to use htaccess to change this not so lovely url

```
http://localhost/test/index.php?page=Article&articleID=61
```

to

```
http://localhost/test/article/2015-09-21-this-is-the-headline
```

From what I've gathered I need to send the last part to a php script which can then get the matching id from the database. Knowing that I should be able to send the user to the original url up top.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/article\/(.*)$ redirect/article.php [L]
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

As of right now I'm not passing the information to the script yet. *redirect/article.php* only contains a print statement to let me know once I get that far.

However, despite my brain and every regex debugger saying otherwise, it won't match the url provided in the second code box. All I'm getting is the good old 404. If I activate the second rule it is applied to my url, telling me that the first one is simply being skipped.

What am I missing?

---

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # rename individual pages
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\/article\/(.*)$ redirect/article.php [L]
    # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php

    # resize images    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.)*\/([0-9]+)\-(([0-9]|[a-z])+)\.(prev)$ filePreview.php?id=$2&size=$3 [L]

    php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
    php_value post_max_size 21M
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You're on the right path. Just do `a2enmod rewrite` and make sure that the rewriting is enabled in `httpd.conf` and you'll be good to go.

Comment: You don't need the backslash escaping for the `/`. It should not cause harm, but is unnecessary.  You mentioned that the `index.php` rule works, which implies that there is likely more to your .htaccess file (we don't see `RewriteEngine On`, for example, but assume it's there). If there are any other lines related to mod_rewrite, please post them.

Comment: Checked and it is in fact enabled. I have another rule in there that works like a charm, but not this one. I'll add the whole .htaccess content to my post.

Comment: In what directory is this .htaccess file? Does it reside at the site root `/` or inside the `test/` directory?

Comment: It is located in the _test_ directory. I had thought of this and tried 
`RewriteBase /test/`
without any change.

Comment: If it is residing in `/test`, then the rule probably needs to be `^article/(.*)` because it won't be preceded by a `/` when .htaccess receives it in that context.

Comment: Yup, that was it, stupid mistake as always. Thank you very much! Is there a way to mark a comment as the correct answer?

Comment: @asto I'll put it as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of a .htaccess file informs how you must list paths for mod_rewrite. Inside .htaccess, paths for `RewriteRule` are not received with a leading `/`.  Since yours was residing in `/test`, the `(.*)` at the start of your rule wasn't matching anything and harmless. Since that was followed by `/`, the `article/` path was expecting a `/` it would never receive.  The simplest fix is to change this rule to match `article` at the start via:

```
RewriteRule ^article/(.*) redirect/article.php [L]
```

Assuming you'll use that as a lookup in the PHP script, add a parameter to use the `$1` captured pattern like:

```
RewriteRule ^article/(.*) redirect/article.php?article=$1 [L]
```