# Htaccess Redirect with Value from Database

Tags: php, .htaccess

After I have already been helped once today ([Htaccess Regex won't match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32955353/htaccess-regex-wont-match/32956760)), I ran right into the next problem, making me wonder if my approach is at all feasible.

I'm still trying to use htaccess to change this not so lovely url

```
http://localhost/test/index.php?page=Article&articleID=61
```

to

```
http://localhost/test/article/2015-09-21-this-is-the-headline
```

Thanks to the previous question I was able to work out the regex and forward the string to a script.

```
RewriteRule ^article\/(.*)$ article.php?id=$1 [L]
```

The script gets the correct id from the database. Most answers I found via google say to use a header to get to the actual location. That however defeats the purpose as it would still change the url to the ugly one.

Instead I tried including the page. Since index.php needs certain parameters I went the ugly way and just saved those manually.

```
<?php
    require_once('config.php');
    require_once(LIB_PATH.'system/DatabaseController.class.php');    
    $dbController = new DatabaseController();

    $id = $dbController->escapeString($_GET['id']);
    $sql = "SELECT articleID FROM ".DATABASE_PREFIX."_article WHERE articleTitleLink = '".$id."'";
    $result = $dbController->getFirstRow($sql);

    if (empty($result)) {
        header('Location: index.php?page=Error404');
        exit();
    } else {
        $_GET['page'] = 'Article';
        $_GET['articleID'] = $result['articleID'];
        include('index.php');
        exit();
    }
```

Doing this worked surprisingly well. It's displaying the correct page

```
index.php?page=Article&articleID=61
```

while showing the nice url

```
article/2015-09-21-this-is-the-headline
```

However, neither is the CSS loaded nor are the images processed by the htaccess. I'm assuming because include doesn't actually execute the php. I feel like I'm either very close to success or completely stuck in a pointless endeavour.

TL;DR: Want to prettify my urls. Requires getting an id from the data, which I achieve via php. Now I'm lost getting to the requested page while maintaining the pretty url. Can my approach work or what would be a better way?

Comment: what does the source code of the final browser output page look like? has all the HTML functionality of the index.php been retained?

Comment: From what I can tell all the HTML has been loaded correctly. As said before the CSS is missing. Plus all the images, since I run those through a script to resize them according to the screen size. Images are sent there via htaccess, which does not appear to be happening here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a base tag to your `head` section so that you can use the relative URL for your CSS.

```
<base href="http://example.com" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
//The CSS file above will load from http://example.com/css/style.css
```

OR

You can add a forward slash before the path in the link tag so that it starts at the root directory.

```
<link href="/path/to/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: So incredibly close I was. :) Thank you!