# URL rewrite with slash

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I try to build a seo friendly url system like stackoverflow.

Example:

```
https://domain.com/cat/{id}/topic-title
```

But, there are issues because url rewrite.

1 - Break links

```
https://domain.com/cat/css/style.css
https://domain.com/cat/img/favicon.png
```

2 - Keep the current directory when navigate

```
https://domain.com/cat/cat/{id}/topic-name
```

my .htaccess

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^cat/(.*)$ category.php?current=$1 [L]
```

my hyperlink

```
<a href="cat/<?php echo $topic; ?>" class="mdl-layout__tab<?php if ($current == $topic) {echo ' is-active';}?>"><?php echo $topic; ?></a>
```

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What's wrong with my url system ?

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957886/htaccess-redirect-with-value-from-database/32957975#32957975) to fix your CSS problem with your rewrite code.

Comment: That's wont work. The main css called from a cdn by absolute link.